# When is it okay to throw out old computer books like Windows 98, Windows 2000?

Tags: active-directory, windows-xp, windows-server-2000, windows-2000

I have a couple of old computer books entitled: Windows 98, Windows NT, Windows 2000 Professional, Windows 2000 Server, Windows 2000 Directory Service Design, Windows 2000 Directory Service Administration and so on... But right now we are in the era where Windows XP it about to be put to sleep and moving in slowly into Windows 7 until they feel to put that to rest as well. I want to get updated books but feel weird throwing out these books, Let me know what I need to do with these books

Comment: This isn't a remotely suitable question for SO. Read the FAQ again. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Seriously? Really this question?

Comment: I give them to my 2-year old so that she will leave the current books alone.

Answer (score 3):

You should put on a red devil suit ( like the BSD Devil mascot ) go to the beach and start a bonfire with them.

Answer (score 0):

If the information is no longer relevant to current versions of windows and you are no longer working with those versions then put them out for recycling. I still have a windows 95 internals book that I keep because I find it interesting from an O/S design POV.